# Searching in an array and matching the values

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have two fields whose names are: Format field and Extension field.

I have to match both the fields like:

```
var format     = $("#someid").val();// Eg value is excel;
var extension  = $("#someid").val();// eg value is xls;
var FormatCheck= {"excel":["xls","xlsx"],"word":["doc","docx"],"html"["htm","html"],"mpp":["mpp"],"pdf":["pdf"],"ppt":["ppt","pptx"]};
```

Then I have to compare  thevalue of Format and Extension fields with the array in `FormatCheck`.

If it matches exactly the array then I have to insert it.

Comment: are you sure that `FormatCheck` is what you want it to be? It looks like JSON, you say it is an array, I would argue its neither...

Comment: no actually i am using like FormatCheck as key,value pair like excel :xls,xlsx, as it's value

Comment: I don't think that what you have fits that purpose...

Comment: Try using 
jQuery.inArray()

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
var format     = $("#format_id").val();// Eg value is excel;
var extension  = $("#ext_id").val();// eg value is xls;
var FormatCheck= [excel["xls","xlsx"],word["doc","docx"],html["htm","html"],mpp["mpp"],pdf["pdf"],ppt["ppt","pptx"]];   //Double dimensional array,

function validExtension(format, extension, FormatCheck){ 
  for(var i = 0 , len = FormatCheck.length; i < len; i++){
     if($.inArray(FormatCheck[format], extension) == 1) return true; //Check if the format exists.
  }
  return false;
}

validExtension("excel","xls", FormatCheck)   //returns true.
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler if your FormatCheck was organized differently:

```
var FormatCheck = {"xls": "excel", "xlsx": "excel", ... }
```

Otherwise, you need to scan the whole table to find the extension:

```
var type = null;
$.each(FormatCheck, function(key,val) {
    if ($.inArray(val, extension) >= 0) {
        type = key;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you do not need jquery for that. You could try this

```
var FormatCheck = "xls,xlsx,doc,docx,html,htm,html,mpp,pdf,ppt,pptx".indexOf($("#someid").val()) > -1;

if(FormatCheck) { /*extension is in range*/}
else { /*it is not*/}
```